# emacs not accepting lambda in after-change-functions

Tags: variables, debugging, emacs

I'm attempting to overload the after-change-functions in a given buffer through a class method. notify-others-of-change is an arbitrary function.

```
(defmethod set-after-change-functions ((server server-class)
                                              name-of-buffer)
  "Adds appropriate after-change-functions to the given name-of-buffer."
  (with-current-buffer name-of-buffer
    (setq-local after-change-functions
                (cons 
                   (lambda (beg end prev-length)
                        (notify-others-of-change
                           server beg end prev-length))
                   after-change-functions))))
```

When attempting to run this on a given buffer (passing in a valid server object, I checked), Emacs yells at me about "symbol's value as variable is void: server" and after-change-functions goes nil, even if there were elements in it before. However, when changed to

```
(defmethod set-after-change-functions ((server server-class)
                                              name-of-buffer)
  "Adds appropriate after-change-functions to the given name-of-buffer."
  (with-current-buffer name-of-buffer
    (setq-local after-change-functions
                (cons
                   #'notify-others-of-change-SIMPLE
                   after-change-functions))))
```

where notify-others-of-change-SIMPLE is the basic after-change function which accepts only three arguments as in the lambda above, everything seems to work. I'd prefer to use a lambda here, but it appears it's not possible. Why is this problem occurring and is it possible to change it to allow lambdas to be used?

Comment: Do you have `lexical-binding` set?  Your lambda function refers to `server`, so it would have to be a closure to work.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24548536/113848).

Comment: Don't use `setq` or `setq-local` for hooks.  Use `add-hook` or `remove-hook`.

Comment: You say "I'd prefer to use a lambda here", but putting lambdas into hook variables unnecessarily is bad practice -- it makes them problematic to update or remove (causing bugs if you're not careful), it makes inspecting the hook difficult (especially if the lambda is byte-compiled), and it makes it impossible to jump to the code of the function definition from the hook.  For all these reasons you should prefer to use named functions in hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Setting lexical-binding to t as a file-local variable as described in the question linked by legoscia, along with making sure to sharp-quote all my lambdas instead of just quoting, managed to fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't quote your lambdas, that macro is self-quoting already.

Comment: Well, it didn't work (maintained the unbound variable message) until I did.

Comment: You mentioned that you used a sharp quote "instead of just quoting". What I'm recommending, is not quoting at all.

Comment: True. The documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html) suggests that both are equivalent; is it a style issue?

Comment: Mostly. This code snippet is public, so it shouldn't show a subpar example.