# Exceed evaluation depth when forward function in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Here is just a simplified code snipped I have not managed to work. I do not understand what is wrong.

```
(defun enumerate-indicies (func)
    (let ((index 0))
        (while (< index 5)
            (funcall func index)
            (setq index (1+ index)))))

(defun enumerate-multiplied-indicies (func)
    (enumerate-indicies #'(lambda (index)
                            (funcall func (* 10 index)))))
```

The following testing code returns `10` as expected:

```
(defun test/enumerate-indicies ()
    (let ((sum 0))
          (enumerate-indicies #'(lambda (index)
                                    (setq sum (+ sum index))))
    sum))

(test/enumerate-indicies)
```

But the below causes `error Lisp nesting exceeds max-lisp-eval-depth` in my Emacs:

```
(defun test/enumerate-multiplied-indicies ()
    (let ((sum 0))
          (enumerate-multiplied-indicies #'(lambda (index)
                                             (setq sum (+ sum index))))
    sum))
(test/enumerate-multiplied-indicies)
```

Could you please give my a clue? That is not supposed be a recursive call here but seems that it is. Thanks.

Comment: Enabling lexical binding fixes it, though I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `lexical-let` to penetrate the `lambda`?  Is the correct answer **100**?

```
(defun enumerate-indicies (func)
  (let ((index 0))
    (while (< index 5)
      (funcall func index)
        (setq index (1+ index)))))

(defun enumerate-multiplied-indicies (func)
  (lexical-let ((func func))
    (enumerate-indicies #'(lambda (index)
      (funcall func (* 10 index))))))

(defun test/enumerate-multiplied-indicies ()
  (lexical-let ((sum 0))
    (enumerate-multiplied-indicies #'(lambda (index)
      (setq sum (+ sum index))))
    sum))

(test/enumerate-multiplied-indicies)
```

Comment: My Emacs 24.5.1 does not have a `lexical-let`. Anyway I do not understand the root of such behavior.

Comment: Oh, I got it. The function is a part of `cl` package. And the code now begins to work. Anyway where can I find details what happens in my broken code snippet and in the yours? I want to understand not just simply use :)

Comment: Here is a link to the the lesson I received from *legoscia* and *lunaryorn*:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24549625/2112489  I'm not a programmer by trade, just a hobbyist who enjoys customizing Emacs -- I recognized your situation as being similar to a previous problem I had encountered.